# Batch set for specific Ip

Tags: batch-file, exception, ip, subnet

I would like to use this batch file :

```
@echo off

cd c:\windows\system32

gpupdate /force

exit
```

to be used only with the computer with specific ip or sub net mask.
so for example if my comp is set in work with the IP 10.110.x.x it has to start and if not(like when I get back home) it cannot be done.

Comment: So the real question is: How do I determine if my notebook/tablet/portable-pc is connected to the work (W)Lan ?

Answer (score 1):

execute code only when computer has an IP of `10.110.x.x`:

```
ipconfig|find "IPv4"|find " 10.110." && (
  cd c:\windows\system32 
  gpupdate /force
)
```

Comment: This should do fine

Answer (score 0):

I used this script and it worked fine :

@echo off
 for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('pathping -n -h 1 -p 10 1.2.3.4 ^| find " 0 "') do @set ipaddress=%%a

if "%ipaddress:~0,10%"=="10.110.40." (

cd c:\windows\system32

gpupdate /force

)

exit

And I tried yours too and it worked fine thank you !